# When killing a process, can I use its' `eax` to save exit status?

Tags: process, operating-system, posix, xv6

I'm taking OS class and we need to extend XV6's `exit()` to support exit status, thus we're writing `exit2(int)`.

I thought of two candidates for the purpose of saving the exit status of the killed process.

1. The first option was to add a variable to `struct proc` for exit status. My problem with this solution is that it involves changing a fundamental structure of the OS for a very little cause, and moreover it means I'm gonna have a garbage integer for every process, which is not the best idea.
2. Second idea was to save the exit status in a trap frame register of the killed process, but then  I have something inside me saying that I should not trust the value of `eax` in the killed process.

What's a better idea? (or less worse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definite answer is no, the purpose of `eax` is to be used as a return value from procedures. In some kernel implementations (I know it works on rev 6 of xv6) this trick MIGHT work but one can not rely on `eax` after a `kill()` as you never know when the kernel will actually kill the process.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 is the easiest and safest.

Option 2, strange as it might sound, can work in xv6.
No memory is freed when a process `exit()`s.
Only when the parent invokes `wait()` the child process memory is freed,
including the child kernel stack.

Since no one is going to use the kernel stack after the child goes `ZOMBIE`,
the exit status can be stored anywhere on the kernel stack.

So you can store the exist status at `proc->kstack-4`
and fetch it in the wait routine from `p->kstack-4`.
Just make sure to fetch it BEFORE the `kfree(p->kstack)`!

Comment: upvote for the deep knowledge in what's going on behind the scenes of XV6, but I'm not sure my professor was looking for this solution.